# Is there a magic link to tags from meta sites?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, magic-links

To create a magic link to a tag of a main site, I can use `[tag: tagName]`. This applies even when I'm in its meta site. Is there a magic link to the tags of the meta site, rather of the main site?

Comment: `[meta-tag:(...)]`